# What is analogue of @PathVariable in Jakarta EE?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

How can I do the same in Jakarta EE?

```java
@GetMapping("/page/{pageNo}")
public String findPaginated(@PathVariable("pageNo") int pageNo) {
    // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you try to ask is the equivalent JAX-RS annotation for spring-mvc 's `@PathVariable` ? It is `@PathParam`.

So given this spring-mvc configuration :

```java
@GetMapping("/page/{pageNo}")
public String findPaginated(@PathVariable("pageNo") int pageNo) {
    
}
```

the equivalent JAX-RS version is :

```java
@GET
@Path("/page/{pageNo}")
public String findPaginated(@PathParam("pageNo") int pageNo) {
    
}
```